# Convert date in to ISO 8601 format

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am trying to take a date and time from a data extension and covert it in to `ISO 8601` is this possible and how?

Is it possible to do this using `AMPScript`?

Comment: I think you mean [ISO 8601](https://xkcd.com/1179/)?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [FormatDate](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/date-time/FormatDate.html):

```
%%=FormatDate(Now(), "YYYY-MM-DD", "", "en-US")=%%
```

It doesn't look like ampscript follows [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), which would use `dd` (Day in month) instead of `DD` (Day in year).

If you want to add time:

```
%%=FormatDate(Now(), "YYYY-MM-DD", "HH:MM:SS", "en-US")=%%
```

If it's like `Apex`, you may be able to insert special characters, but I don't know if you can remove the space.

```
%%=FormatDate(Now(), "YYYY-MM-DD\"T\"", "HH:MM:SS\"Z\"", "en-US")=%%
```

Comment: Is this the same if i need this format 2016-03-18T08:01:00z

Comment: @Peter then it's not really ISO-8601?

Comment: What would be a proper format of this statement: %%=FormatDate(Now(), "YYYY-MM-DD\"T\"", "HH:MM:SS\"Z\"", "en-US")=%%

to receive such date: '2014-11-20T14:23:44.00+00:00'  ?

The one provided above doesn't work. @AdrianLarson